# using jQuery selector with a dom element

Tags: dom, object, jquery-selectors, parameter-passing

I have a javascript function that receives a dom element as a parameter. In this function I am trying to get to the closest ancestor 'form'. I wanted to use:

```
function submit_form(obj)
{
    var form1 = $(obj).closest("form");
    alert (form1.id);
}
```

here obj is a dom element of submit type. I just don't seem to get it working.
Could someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
function submit_form(obj)
{
    var form1 = $(obj).closest("form")[0];  
    alert (form1.id);
}
```

The result of jQuery selection/traversal functions *always* is an array, possibly with one element only, but still an array. Index into the array to get actual DOM elements.

However, you can do this without jQuery as long as `obj` is an input/select/textarea element.

```
function submit_form(obj)
{
    var form1 = obj.form;  
    alert (form1.id);
}
```

For the sake of completeness, you could also stay within jQuery and do

```
function submit_form(obj)
{
    var $form1 = $(obj).closest("form");
    alert ( $form1.attr("id") );
}
```

Comment: you are f***ing genius!! thank you ;) i have to wait 3 more minutes before I can mark this answer correct!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
function closest(obj, tagName) {

   // Go up in the tree until you find the ancestor form
   while (obj.parent !== null) {
      if (obj.nodeType === 1) {
         parent = obj.parentNode;
         if (parent.tagName === tagName) {
            return parent;
         }
      }   
   }

   // If no form exists return null
   if (obj.tagName !== tagName) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Use it in this way

```
var closestForm = closest(obj, 'FORM')
```

Answer (score 1):

`form1` would be a jQuery object, so you can either use `.attr("id")`, or access the DOM element itself using `[0].id`:

```
var form1 = $(obj).closest("form");
alert(form1.attr("id"));

var form2 = $(obj).closest("form")[0];
alert(form2.id);
```